# How to get items in order by min to max and move to temp list C#

Tags: c#

So i am trying to take a list of items and get it so that it is ordered by the min value first and so on. Then i wish to have it moved to a temporary list and check to see if the next item is equal to the previous by adding on and so forth. 
this is what i have done so far, but it is going from max to min, so i have it subtracting 1 instead of adding.

```
if (CurrentCards.OrderBy(n => n.Total).ToList()[0].Total == CurrentCards[1].Total - 1 && CurrentCards[1].Total ==
                CurrentCards[2].Total - 1 && CurrentCards[2].Total == CurrentCards[3].Total - 1 &&
                CurrentCards[3].Total == CurrentCards[4].Total - 1)
```

What is it that i am doing incorrectly?
Is it that i need to use the OrderBy for each of the items?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unclear to me, do you want to get all that have a equal value and copy to a new list, or do you want to get distinct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong.

```
CurrentCards.OrderBy(n => n.Total).ToList()[0]
```

creates new list, from which you then get first item. Original list remains same.

```
CurrentCards[1]
```

then takes second item from original unsorted list.

You should orer your list and save it and work with this saved one.

```
var orderedCards = CurrentCards.OrderBy(n => n.Total).ToList();
```

And then you should use `for` cycle and temporal variable.

```
bool temp = true;

// dont forget to add check if your list has enought items

for(int i = 0;i<orderedCards.Count()-1;i++)
{
   temp = temp && orderedCards[i].Total == orderedCards[i+1].Total + 1
}

if (temp) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds what you're trying to do is a bubble sort.  Here's a link to a sample C# bubble sort:  http://www.publicjoe.f9.co.uk/csharp/sort01.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your question 100% and especially with this part:

> ... check to see if the next item is equal to the previous by adding on...

You have **-1**'s in your code and, with your usage, you'll only check if adjacent values differ by one.

If you the totals that aren't 1, try a group by (code below is untested):

```
// this should be a list of anonymous objects that are effectively
// <int, int> tuples
var nonDistinct = CurrentCards.GroupBy(
                   card => card.Total, 
                   (total, cards) => new { Total = total, Count = cards.Count()})
                   .Where(obj => obj.Count > 1);
```